# Cefsharp Visual Studio Get Link Url

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, webbrowser-control, chromium-embedded

I am building a web browser with visual studio cefsharp. I have been struggling to find a way to find the url of a specific link (on an action like right-click or mouseover). In other words, when I right-click a link, I would like to store the url in a variable. I found this: http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=12635
Which I believe would solve my problem but am not sure how to use it. If anyone could explain this link or suggest a new solution, I would appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve]

Comment: @Mat'sMug.  I am not seeking debugging help, I am simply unsure how to proceed and looking for advise on how I should approach this problem

Comment: Ok sorry, wrong close reason. Your question is *too broad* to be a good fit on this site, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Asking for off-site resources or tutorials is also off-topic. Did you read the [help/on-topic] page?

Comment: @Mat'sMug ok, thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using CEF, not CefSharp. So I'll try to guess how it is going to work in CefSharp. When you right click anything in the browser the context menu shows up. There is a way to create a custom handler for the context menu. [This](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/449/how-to-add-new-items-to-the-native-context-menu-on-a-cefsharp-control-in-winforms) tutorial has some details.

The 4th parameter of `OnBeforeContextMenu` is `IContextMenuParams`. If I understand your question correctly you are looking for `LinkUrl` [property](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cd934267c65f494ceb9ee75995cd2a1ca0954543/CefSharp/IContextMenuParams.cs#L36).